# Hayes Nine Hydro brakes - oil

Tags: brakes

do you think that I could use Shimano mineral oil on/in Hayes Nine Hydro brakes (where it says Dot 4).

Thanks for your help people!

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49827/what-to-replace-after-using-wrong-hydraulic-fluid

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you that mineral oil is easier to get than DOT4?

Comment: only because I have some mineral one / shimano in the house, instead I will need to buy the Dot 4. I will move house soon and often I bought bottles and then did not use them more then once.
Dot 4 is very easy to find anyway.

Answer (score 4):

No. Can not, must not. Fluid type mismatches in either direction can make seals and other non-metal parts degrade, swell, and/or fail. Mineral oil, being the less caustic and reactive one, will generally do it more gradually when this mistake does get made, but it still does it or at least can.

Comment: I imagined so, that there was an effect on the seals and so to safety, and I appreciate your input, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not if you want the brakes to continue working normally, No.

Manufacturers design their brake systems to work with a specific kind of fluid.  Mineral oil and DOT fluid have different properties and are not interchangeable.

In your case (putting mineral oil in a DOT system) I believe the seals may/can swell and the brakes will become unusable.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it.
And as someone asked Dot 4 is easy to find everywhere, more than shimano.
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Using LHM+ liquid for all my shimano brakes (3 bikes in a house) for last two years (started using as a winter oil, because shimano's one had problems). It is cheap, and it has no problems in winter (in my climate, temperature can drop to -10 °C).

LHM+ is some way better than DOT4 in low temperatures and it it little more 'softer'

No problems yet.

But do it on your own risk.

Comment: Of course, any change you do, then you ride it and it is at your own risk.

Comment: I live in Estonia, it gets very cold here and grease (like in hubs) should not be too much because it freezes.
I like shimano oil because it is organic and do not ruin components over time. In this case I had some so I was thinking to try shimano on hayes. I ended up asking a shop to sell to me just  a tiny bit, and they did, spending just 1 euro.
On  the other hand servicing hayes without the right tools was hard(er).